# How to get a list of leaf subdirectories in a root folder in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I am very new to Perl (scripting languages in general) and I was wondering how to use Perl to get a lisitng of all the leaf directories in Perl. For example, lets say my root directory is C:

```
C: -> I have folder "A" and "B" and files a.txt and b.txt

Folder "A" -> I have folder "D" and file c.html
Folder "B" -> I have folder "E" and "F" and file d.html 
Folder "D", "E" and "F" -> bunch of text files
```

How do I get a bunch of directory paths as output for this scenario of:

```
C:\A\D\
C:\B\E\
C:\B\F\
```

As you can see, I just want a list of all the leaf directories possible. I dont want C:\A\ and C:\B\ to show up. After doign some reserarch myself, I have noticed that I may somehow be able to use the File::Find module in Perl, but that also I am not 100% sure about how to go ahead with.

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an [answer to the question *How to Get the Last Subdirectories* by liverpole on Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=828144):

prints all leaf directories under the current directory (see `"./"`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $h_dirs = terminal_subdirs("./");
my @dirs   = sort keys %$h_dirs;
print "Terminal Directories:\n", join("\n", @dirs);

sub terminal_subdirs {
    my ($top, $h_results) = @_;
    $h_results ||= { };
    opendir(my $dh, $top) or die "Arrggghhhh -- can't open '$top' ($!)\n";
    my @files = readdir($dh);
    closedir $dh;
    my $nsubdirs = 0;
    foreach my $fn (@files) {
        next if ($fn eq '.' or $fn eq '..');
        my $full = "$top/$fn";
        if (!-l $full and -d $full) {
            ++$nsubdirs;
            terminal_subdirs($full, $h_results);
        }
    }

    $nsubdirs or $h_results->{$top} = 1;
    return $h_results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use File::Find::Rule qw( );
use Path::Class      qw( dir );

my $root = dir('.')->absolute();

my @dirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in($root);
shift(@dirs);

my @leaf_dirs;
if (@dirs) {
   my $last = shift(@dirs);
   for (@dirs) {
      push @leaf_dirs, $last if !/^\Q$last/;
      $last = $_ . "/";
   }
   push @leaf_dirs, $last;
}

say for @leaf_dirs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `find`'s  `preprocess` option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find({  wanted    =>sub{1}, # required--in version 5.8.4 at least
        preprocess=>sub{    # @_ is files in current directory
            @_ = grep { -d && !/\.{1,2}$/ } @_;
            print "$File::Find::dir\n" unless @_;
            return @_;
        }
    }, ".");
```